# Изменить цвет в варианте иконки на css :before

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Есть такая иконка 'конверта':

```js
function fn1() {

  document.getElementById('mail').style.borderLeftColor = '#cccccc';
  document.getElementById('mail').style.borderRightColor = '#cccccc';
  document.getElementById('mail').style.borderBottomColor = '#c2c2c2';
  document.getElementById('mail').style.borderTopColor = 'grey';
  // ? _изменить красный цвет сверху;
}
```

```css
#tbl {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 8px;
}
#tbl tbody td {
  width: 200px;
  height: 54px;
}
#mail {
  font-size: 12px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  border-top: 1em solid transparent;
  border-left: 1.5em solid red;
  border-right: 1.5em solid red;
  border-bottom: 1em solid red;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
#mail:before {
  content: '';
  top: -1.23em;
  left: -1.5em;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 1em solid red;
  border-left: 1.5em solid transparent;
  border-right: 1.5em solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 1em solid transparent;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="1: Изменить цвет иконки." style="width:200px; height:28px; font-size:12px" onclick="fn1()">
</br>
<table id="tbl">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>H1</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr style="background:#f5f5f5;">
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background:#f5f5f5;">
      <td>

        <div id="mail"></div>
        <div style="margin-top:-14px; font-size:10px; font-weight:bold;">&nbsp;&nbsp; 8 | 33</div>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background:#f5f5f5;">
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>F2</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

При нажатии на кнопку 'Изменить цвет иконки', - сверху остается красный треугольник.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как изменить этот красный цвет на любой иной?

Comment: через `js` к псевдо элементам нельзя обратися. В качестве решения можно заменить `:before` на `span` или менять цвет `:before` через дополнительный класс элемента `#main1`

Comment: @Olegatro, Вы бы не могли привести код? Никак не пойму, уж перепробовал ... Может лучше отказаться от такого варианта _иконки_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function setColorBeforeBorder(e, f, g) {
   for (var d = document.styleSheets, b = 0; b < d.length; b++)
     for (var c = d[b].cssRules, a = 0; a < c.length; a++)
       c[a].selectorText == e && (c[a].style[f] = g)
 };

 function fn1(color) {
   setColorBeforeBorder('#mail', 'border-left-color', color);
   setColorBeforeBorder('#mail', 'border-right-color', color);
   setColorBeforeBorder('#mail', 'border-bottom-color', color);
   setColorBeforeBorder('#mail::before', 'border-top-color', color);
 }
```

```css
#tbl {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 8px;
}
#tbl tbody td {
  width: 200px;
  height: 54px;
}
#mail {
  font-size: 12px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  border-top: 1em solid transparent;
  border-left: 1.5em solid red;
  border-right: 1.5em solid red;
  border-bottom: 1em solid red;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
#mail:before {
  content: '';
  top: -1.23em;
  left: -1.5em;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 1em solid red;
  border-left: 1.5em solid transparent;
  border-right: 1.5em solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 1em solid transparent;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="1: Изменить цвет иконки." style="width:200px; height:28px; font-size:12px" onclick="fn1('#CCCCCC')">
</br>
<table id="tbl">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>H1</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr style="background:#f5f5f5;">
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background:#f5f5f5;">
      <td>

        <div id="mail"></div>
        <div style="margin-top:-14px; font-size:10px; font-weight:bold;">&nbsp;&nbsp; 8 | 33</div>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background:#f5f5f5;">
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>F2</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Изменение цвета :before, чтобы посмотреть запустите код выше, если необходимо в onclick кнопки пропишите нужный цвет

Comment: архи-круто, спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Решение через добавление класса:

```js
function fn1() {

  document.getElementById('mail').className = 'changed';
}
```

```css
#tbl {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 8px;
}
#tbl tbody td {
  width: 200px;
  height: 54px;
}
#mail {
  font-size: 12px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  border-top: 1em solid transparent;
  border-left: 1.5em solid red;
  border-right: 1.5em solid red;
  border-bottom: 1em solid red;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
#mail:before {
  content: '';
  top: -1.23em;
  left: -1.5em;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 1em solid red;
  border-left: 1.5em solid transparent;
  border-right: 1.5em solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 1em solid transparent;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

#mail.changed {
  border-left-color: #ccc;
  border-right-color: #ccc;
  border-bottom-color: #c2c2c2; 
  border-top-color: grey;
}

#mail.changed:before {
  border-top-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="1: Изменить цвет иконки." style="width:200px; height:28px; font-size:12px" onclick="fn1()">
</br>
<table id="tbl">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>H1</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr style="background:#f5f5f5;">
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background:#f5f5f5;">
      <td>

        <div id="mail"></div>
        <div style="margin-top:-14px; font-size:10px; font-weight:bold;">&nbsp;&nbsp; 8 | 33</div>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background:#f5f5f5;">
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>F2</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Что касается вопроса про отказаться от такого варианта иконки, то зависит от того, должны ли разные части конверта быть разного цвета. Если нет, то я бы конечно предпочел использовать `svg` иконку или иконочный шрифт на худой конец.

Comment: спасибо за совет и помощь.